# Python Click: Exception Handling under setuptools

Tags: python, exception, setuptools, python-click

I have a [python click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) application that works great, but I want to be notified whenever a user types in an unknown command. For example, if `mycli foo` is valid, but they type in `mycli bar`, I want to override the default exception handling behavior and fire off an error to an error tracker, such as rollbar.

I found [this page](http://click.pocoo.org/5/exceptions/) which describes how to override the exception handling, but it assumes I have a `Command`. The problem I've run into is that I've also integrated with setuptools by following [this guide](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/), and it points to my `Command` in the `[console_scripts]` section. For example, `yourscript=yourscript:cli` points to the `cli` command.

I'm not sure how to call `cli.main()` from within `[console_scripts]` or if that's even the right way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a custom `click.Command` class, you can capture the invoking command line and then report any error in the command line in an exception handler using a custom class like:

#### Custom Class

```
def CatchAllExceptions(cls, handler):

    class Cls(cls):

        _original_args = None

        def make_context(self, info_name, args, parent=None, **extra):

            # grab the original command line arguments
            self._original_args = ' '.join(args)

            try:
                return super(Cls, self).make_context(
                    info_name, args, parent=parent, **extra)
            except Exception as exc:
                # call the handler
                handler(self, info_name, exc)

                # let the user see the original error
                raise

        def invoke(self, ctx):
            try:
                return super(Cls, self).invoke(ctx)
            except Exception as exc:
                # call the handler
                handler(self, ctx.info_name, exc)

                # let the user see the original error
                raise

    return Cls


def handle_exception(cmd, info_name, exc):
    # send error info to rollbar, etc, here
    click.echo(':: Command line: {} {}'.format(info_name, cmd._original_args))
    click.echo(':: Raised error: {}'.format(exc))
```

#### Using the custom class

Then to use the custom command/group, pass it as the `cls` argument to the `click.command` or `click.group` decorator like one of:

```
@click.command(cls=CatchAllExceptions(click.Command, handler=report_exception))

@click.group(cls=CatchAllExceptions(click.Group, handler=report_exception))

@click.group(cls=CatchAllExceptions(click.MultiCommand, handler=report_exception))
```

Note the need to specify which `click.Command` subclass is required as well as
the handler to send the exception information to.

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` and `@click.command()` decorators usually instantiates a `click.Group` or `click.Command` objects, but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` (etc) in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Command.make_context()` to grab the original command line, and `click.Command.invoke()` to catch the exception and then call our exception handler.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group(cls=CatchAllExceptions(click.Group, handler=report_exception))
def cli():
    """A wonderful test program"""
    pass

@cli.command()
def foo():
    """A fooey command"""
    click.echo('Foo!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'foo',
        'foo --unknown',
        'foo still unknown',
        '',
        '--help',
        'foo --help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> foo
Foo!
-----------
> foo --unknown
Error: no such option: --unknown
:: Command line: test.py foo --unknown
:: Raised error: no such option: --unknown
-----------
> foo still unknown
:: Command line: test.py foo still unknown
:: Raised error: Got unexpected extra arguments (still unknown)
Usage: test.py foo [OPTIONS]

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (still unknown)
-----------
> 
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  A wonderful test program

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  foo  A fooey command
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  A wonderful test program

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  foo  A fooey command
-----------
> foo --help
Usage: test.py foo [OPTIONS]

  A fooey command

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Worked out of the box! Thank you!